# fluxible - my store is receiving data, but my component is not able to talk to the store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, fluxible

Basically, on loading the home page, an action is triggered that grabs data from the database in JSON form.  It dispatches a SUCCESS that my store receives and updates the state of an object, `posts`.  When I `console.log()` from the store, I see the data has indeed been received.  However, my component is not getting that data.

Here's my component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import connectToStores from 'fluxible-addons-react/connectToStores';
import PostStore from '../stores/PostStore';

class Home extends React.Component {

  render() {
      return (
          <div>
              <h2>Home</h2>
              <div></div>
          </div>
      );
  }
}

Home = connectToStores(Home, [PostStore], (context, props) => ({
    posts : context.getStore(PostStore).getPosts()
}))

export default Home;
```

I don't see the posts data in the props in React Developer Tools.

Here's the store:

```
import BaseStore from 'fluxible/addons/BaseStore';

class PostStore extends BaseStore {

    constructor(dispatcher) {
        super(dispatcher);
        this.posts = null;
    }

    handleGetPostsSuccess(payload) {
        this.posts = payload;
        console.log("from PostStore",this.posts);
        this.emitChange();
    }

    getPosts() {
        return this.posts;
    }

    //send state to client
    dehydrate() {
        return {
            posts : this.posts
        }
    }

    //server state
    rehydrate(state) {
        this.posts = state.posts;
    }

}

PostStore.storeName = 'PostStore';
PostStore.handlers = {
    'GET_POSTS_SUCCESS' : 'handleGetPostsSuccess'
};

export default PostStore;
```

Can someone please help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Where and when you trigger the action?

Answer (score 0):

It look like you are not providing context to your application. You need to instantiate your Fluxible app at the [top-level React component](http://fluxible.io/addons/FluxibleComponent.html).

In order to resolve it, make a new top-level component and set it as your entry point like so:

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Fluxible from 'fluxible';
import { FluxibleComponent } from 'fluxible-addons-react';
import Home from './components/Home';

const app = new Fluxible();
app.registerStore(PostStore);

const context = app.createContext();

ReactDOM.render(
    <FluxibleComponent context={context.getComponentContext()}>
        <Home />
    </FluxibleComponent>,
    document.querySelector('.container')
);
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { provideContext, connectToStores } from 'fluxible-addons-react';
import PostStore from '../stores/PostStore';
import postActions from '../actions/postActions';

class Home extends React.Component {

    dispatchAction() {
        this.context.executeAction(postActions.dispatchPost, { post: 'My Post' });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.dispatchAction.bind(this)}>
                <h2>Home</h2>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Home.contextTypes = {
    getStore: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    executeAction: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

Home = provideContext(Home);

Home = connectToStores(Home, [PostStore], (context) => {
    return {
        posts: context.getStore(PostStore).getPosts()
    };
});

export default Home;
```

**postActions.js**

```
module.exports = {
    dispatchPost(actionContext, payload) {
        actionContext.dispatch('GET_POSTS_SUCCESS', payload);
    }
};
```

That should work!